# filename change in Linux

Tags: linux, awk, rename

I am quite new to `awk` and linux scripting. Need your help to modify the file generation:

Current output: `A20211126.0200+0500-0215+0500.xml`

Expected output: `A20211126.0200-0215.xml`

for all the files in a particular directory.

I want to use a crontab as well to ensure the file names with +0500 is checked and if found then convert the same as mentioned in the expected output.

Thanks All.

I did the following to achieve the desired output.

```
for file in *.xml ; do mv $file ${file//+0500/} ; done
```

now I am able to remove the +0500 part

Comment: (1) You don’t rename files with `awk`. (Not that you couldn’t, but it’s not the right tool for the purpose.) (2) Please show your code. (3) Please describe what you are trying to achieve and what are the inputs. (You are only showing outputs.) (4) Also, strictly *avoid* using `cron`, `crontab` or any such outdated stuff on Linux. In 2021 one would simply define `systemd` `.timer` units for periodic tasks. (`cron` has always been a severely flawed idea and nowadays it is also outdated on top of that.)

Comment: The requirement is only to modify all the file names which will be generated with this naming format A20211126.0200+0500-0215+0500.xml to A20211126.0200-0215.xml

Comment: "for file in *.xml ; do mv $file ${file//+0500/} ; done"

now i am able to remove the +0500 part

Comment: Instead of this extra step of renaming files, can you fix the process that creates them?

Comment: Dou you have access to Perl's standalone `rename` or `prename` command?

Answer (score 0):

If you have perl prename available, then you can use `rename` to achieve this with regex.

If it is not available, you can install it via perls `cpan` (similar to pip) and then replace util-linux version that should be installed by default.

`Perl` will need to be available to use `CPAN`

```
$ ls
A20211126.0200+0500-0215+0500.xml
$ rename 's/([^+]*)[^-]*([^+]*)[^.]*(.*)/$1$2$3/' *.xml
$ ls
A20211126.0200-0215.xml
```